# How to display message to user when machine is rebooted by ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to reboot machine using ansible and want to display broad cast message to users when rebooted is triggered by ansible . I am using below lines in playbook. but it is not displaying any message to user not even the default one .

```
   - name: Machine Reboot
     reboot:
       msg: "Reboot triggered by Ansible"
```

Comment: Because you are already using the documented approach, we will need much more information about your environment, setup and configuration.

Comment: ansible [core 2.11.6] 
 python version = 3.6.0 (default, Jan 13 2017, 19:08:48) [GCC 4.8.2]

Comment: Iam running playbook from another different server and not from ansible tower

Answer (score 0):

You can add `command: wall reboot from Ansible` to your playbook before doing the actual reboot.

For handlers it can look like this:

```
handlers:
 - name: reboot notify
   become: true
   command: wall reboot with love from ansible
   listen: reboot
 - name: reboot
   become: true
   reboot:
```